# Change the HTML of an Expanding Row

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am looking to have a `+` change to a `-` when my table row expands. I have provided my code below and also through JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/k37f0cbp/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .attr("title", "click")
    .click(function() {
      $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();
    });
  $('tr[@class^=child-]').children('td').hide();
});
$if(('tr[@class^=child-]').is(":visible")).click(function() {
  $('.plus', this).html('-');
});
```

```css
th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

[class*='child-row'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parent" id="row1" title="click">
      <td><span class="plus">+</span></td>
      <td>Paper Idea One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row1">
      <td>testing</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not an answer but general suggestion.I'd move the css of `cursor: pointer` to the css file since it isn't something that changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
 {
        //add a flag
        var expanded = false;
        $('tr.parent')  
            .css("cursor", "pointer")  
            .attr("title", "click")  
            .click(function ()
            {  
                $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();
        //check flag, update value of a button and update a flag
                if(expanded)
                {
                    $(".plus").text("+");
                  expanded = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $(".plus").text("-");
                  expanded = true;
                }                                        
            });  
        $('tr[@class^=child-]').children('td').hide();
   });
   $if (('tr[@class^=child-]').is(":visible")).click(function()
   {
        $('.plus', this).html('-');
   });
```

Comment: This works when there is one row, but sadly does not work when there are multiple rows. I think the expanded variable gets over-written and confused. Any suggestions on how to tackle that?

Answer (score 0):

After many more hours exploring this, I combined what the contributor above added with some other things I experimented with and came up with a more elegant and accurate answer that accounts for multiple rows. The only trick here is adding an `id` to the `plus` element that is equivalent to the `parents` `id`.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    $('tr.parent')  
      .css("cursor", "pointer")  
      .attr("title", "click")  
      .click(function ()
             {  
        $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();
        var s = this.id;
        if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
            $('#' + s + '.plus').html('-');
        }
        if ($(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
            $('#' + s + '.plus').html('+');
        }
    })
)};
```